# Pipe return value of a function to subprocess in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, subprocess, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Disclaimer: Just starting to learn python, forgive me for noobish questions or explanations.

**EDIT-** I just hacked around with the core issue I was facing with something like:

```
def to():
    print('To...')
    
    data = ' '.join(req(urls))
    
    p2 = subprocess.run(['bash-tool'], text=True, capture_output=True, input=data)
    p3 = subprocess.run(["another-tool"], text=True, capture_output=True, input=p2.stdout)

    with open(test + '-check', 'w') as f:
        subprocess.run(['sort', '-u'], text=True, stdout=f, input=p3.stdout)
    another-func()
```

Not sure if this is the right approach. As I think it'd break if there are large number of URLs(>10k). And also would probably be quite slow?

**What am I trying to achieve?**

To request some urls(in a fast asynchronous way or using threading/multiprocessing), save the responses, grep certain things from them and save it to a text file. Can be easily done using bash, but I want it to be scalable for future additions and to learn the concepts of python, python networking and multithreading/processing.

**The Problem:**

This following function performs get requests and returns the body of pages.

```
import subprocess
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def req(urls):
    print('\nRequesting...')

    results = pool.map(requests.get, urls)
    return [(result.text) for result in results]
```

I want to pass the results(or pipe to be precise) or the return value to another function which has subprocess calls to a bash command/tool.(Something like `echo 'abc' | bash-tool | another-tool | sort -u >> out.txt`:

```
def to():
    print('To...')
    
    <Cat the return value here and pass it to below subprocesses>
    
    p2 = subprocess.run(['bash-tool'], text=True, capture_output=True, input=p1.stdout)
    p3 = subprocess.run(["another-tool"], text=True, capture_output=True, input=p2.stdout)

    with open(test + '-check', 'w') as f:
        subprocess.run(['sort', '-u'], text=True, stdout=f, input=p3.stdout)
    another-func()
```

So the whole program will be something like:

```
import os
import argparse
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import subprocess
import requests

def req(urls):
    print('\nRequesting...')

    results = pool.map(requests.get, urls)
    return [(result.text) for result in results]


def to():
    print('To...')
    
    <Cat the return value here and pass it to below subprocesses>
    
    p2 = subprocess.run(['bash-tool'], text=True, capture_output=True, input=p1.stdout)
    p3 = subprocess.run(["another-tool"], text=True, capture_output=True, input=p2.stdout)

    with open(test + '-check', 'w') as f:
        subprocess.run(['sort', '-u'], text=True, stdout=f, input=p3.stdout)
    another-func()


def another-func():
     
    <Some more bash-fu>


def main():
    with open(dom,'r') as fl:
        urls=fl.read().splitlines()
    req(urls)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = ThreadPool(int(threads))
    main()
```

I can store the return value of req() to a variable in To(), something like `data = req(urls)` but how can I `echo` the value of "data" variable to be piped using subprocess?

Also let me know if I'm maybe approaching it with a somewhat bad logic maybe? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check the capture_output option https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run. I'm not sure if I understood the problem there, but you should give it a check, it allows piping between processes.

Comment: Well, I figured a hack for it after 5 minutes of posting the question, so yeah :P And yes as you can see I already have used capture_output. But the return value from the previous function is python code and thus couldn't pipe it to the next subprocess, or so I thought. I'll just edit the question and add the workaround I came up with. Still not sure if it's the right approach but it works as of now!